# Accessing JSON Array of Objects in React Native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I'm getting some data from an api as a JSON response. This is a sample of how the data looks like :

```
Array [
 Object {
   "cashless_identifier": "N/A",
   "controlled_parking_zone": "CA-C",
   "disclaimer": "The information provider and/ or licensor are not liable for any errors or omissions contained within this dataset and shall not be liable for any loss, injury or damage caused by its use.",
   "easting": "530868",
   "epsg_27700_well_known_text_geometry": "LINESTRING (530865.6180417204 181481.26078470872,530863.7711480337 181480.49100505587,530872.4696874953 181460.3867598362,530874.555687954 181461.17653376574)",
   "epsg_4326_well_known_text_geometry": "LINESTRING (-0.11531456604058134 51.5171043712184,-0.11534145426089688 51.517097880725345,-0.11522362265321448 51.51691519531169,-0.11519328303934162 51.516921810131386)",
   "last_uploaded": "2019-11-18T23:01:51.000",
   "latitude": "51.517003",
   "location": Object {
     "human_address": "{\"address\": \"\", \"city\": \"\", \"state\": \"\", \"zip\": \"\"}",
     "latitude": "51.517003",
     "longitude": "-0.115284",
   },
   "longitude": "-0.115284",
   "maximum_stay": "N/A",
   "nearest_machine": "N/A",
   "northing": "181470",
   "organisation_uri": Object {
     "url": "http://opendatacommunities.org/id/london-borough-council/camden",
   },
   "parking_bay_length_metres": "22",
   "postcode": "WC2A 3PD",
   "restriction_type": "taxi rank",
   "road_name": "Lincoln's Inn Fields",
   "spatial_accuracy": "Defined By Custodian",
   "tariff": "N/A",
   "times_of_operation": "at any time",
   "unique_identifier": "46042626",
   "valid_parking_permits": "N/A",
 }, .........
```

There are many objects returned inside the array. My question is, how do I access each object individually?. This is how I store the array:

```
const [parkingSpaces,setparkingSpaces] = useState([])
setparkingSpaces(response.data)
```

so if I do parkingSpaces.length , this will return the length of the array. However, I have no clue how I can access each object individually and its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what you're doing here:

- if you are rendering the data out in a form of list, then you just map over the data, rendering an element for each one (so for example with a FlatList, you just dump that array in as the data prop). Then you have access to each one individually, and you render a component for each one that takes whatever you need from each object as props.
- if you want to access each item individually, you must have something in each of those objects that you want to select the item by. In which case you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the correct item, or you can normalise the incoming array to an object keyed by the thing you want to select by.

So for example

```
function arrToDict(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, [item[key]]: item }));
}
```

Then

```
setParkingSpaces(arrToDict(yourApiResponse)
```

As I say though, need more information on usage: this should just be basic JS, but don't have enough context atm -- I'll edit my answer once I'm a bit clearer on what's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I don't want to render it, at the moment I just want to be able to console.log() each object individually. Sorry for not giving enough context, I'm quite new.

Comment: Can you show the full component where you're fetching the data, and also how you aim to use it (I understand how you're storing it, that's fine, and that currently you just want to log to check it, but it would be helpful to see the context). Also what property on the parking space object do you want to use to select -- you want to look at one, but what would you want to use as a key to select the one you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to handle each object inside the array using its corresponding index.
It will suffice your application.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how I can se setParkingSpaces.map()?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your given example, you can use javascript map funtion to iterate through array f objects, Sample code is given below

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
{
  setParkingSpaces.length > 0 &&
  setParkingSpaces.map((item, index) => {

    return(
      <View style={styles.eachItem} key={"items-"+index}>
        ...........
        <Text>{item.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>{item.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>{item.cashless_identifier}</Text>
        ..........
      </View>
    )
  })
}
</View>
```